# Opening local batch file from Chrome bookmark

Tags: google-chrome, batch-file, bookmarks

I have a batch file located at `C:/bat.bat` on the C drive of my Windows 8 system. I created a Chrome bookmark that points to the URL `file:\\\C:\bat.bat`. When I click the bookmark, Chrome shows the contents of the batch file instead of starting the batch file. How can I get Chrome to run the batch file when the bookmark is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

> [Local Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/local-explorer-file-manag/eokekhgpaakbkfkmjjcbffibkencdfkl) - File Manager for Chrome, open files and folders
>   on local directories or network shares
>
> - On Windows, please download and install this app http://goo.gl/trX9bB for Windows Explorer integration, just run
>     "LocalExplorer-Setup.exe" once then you're ready to go.

You need only integration app after install it try to run in address bar or add to bookmark(ctrl+d->change url):

```
localexplorer:C:\bat.bat
```

Select checkbox "remember my choice", if dont want see warning window again. App also will work with any browser.

This is not security solution.

[How does it works?](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: Firefox can do it way more easily with addons. There Also [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/open-with-external-applic/hccmhjmmfdfncbfpogafcbpaebclgjcp) for Chrome based on SimpleGet Chromium extension. But work only with links and i failed run bat also only 1 item can be executed.